# VARCHAR LENGTH?

Tags: sqlite, varchar

What is the VARCHAR length in Sqlite ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages, particularly [ask], before your next post here. Good luck.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you talking about `VARCHAR(##)` or something like https://sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite doesn't place an explicit limit on the length of the `VARCHAR`, however the maximum length of any string or blob is limited to the [maximum length](https://sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length) value, which is 1 billion by default.

You can increase or decrease this limit as well, though. So you're really only limited by the memory you have available.